# Recommend jQuery 1.6.4 ajax PHP form mail scripts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

**Recommend jQuery 1.6.4 ajax php form mail scripts?**

I've been searching for script that fit jQuery 1.6.4 ajax php that I can use. Quite a lot that I've come across is part of script that is taking alot of time to put together. Is there anything that is clearly descriptive from start to finish. A form with check.php script too if that is possible.

I'm using a jQuery 1.6.4 form mail using ajax post with php script. A jQuery error message if a single input field is not filled.

To register a ID number and select module subject 1 or subject 2 with  and submit. This will go to subjectData.mysql database

I've already designed a form mail using a jQuery 1.6.4.

```
<div class="field"><!-- Start Login--> 
     <form action="register.php" method="post" class="register">
         <fieldset class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
         <label for="textinput1"><strong>Log in to register a module</strong></label>
         <input id="textinput1" placeholder="people number" type="text"  /></fieldset>
         <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
         <input id="textinput2" placeholder="Password" type="password" /></fieldset> 
         <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
         <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-mini-1" value="modNo1" checked="checked" />

         <label for="radio-mini-1">subject 1</label>
         <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-mini-2" value="modNo2"  />
         <label for="radio-mini-2">subject 2</label></fieldset>
         <input type="submit" data-theme="a" name="submit" value="Register" />
         <button data-theme="b" id="reset" type="reset">Reset</button>
     </form>
</div>

         <!-- END Login-->
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want check.php to do exactly? You could use any form mail script on the php side... you jsut send the values to php as normal and have it process the data.

Comment: to register a ID number and select module subject 1 or subject 2 with <label for="radio-mini-1"> and submit. This will go to subjectData.mysql database

Comment: It sounds like you dont need a formmail script but rather need to write a script to store your data and then possibly send a mail. Do you know PHP at all because youre probably not going to jsut find something that you can change some config settings and it magically works.

Comment: I've limit PHP skills that I can edit to a right field. I can design websites but never go near php. It is now time for me to grasp this.

Comment: prodigitalson: I would appreciate if you can point me to a right direction. I do need to send a PeopleID and module selection 1 or 2 (not both) and register.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with prodigitalson, you need to know some php to write the code you need and build the response with php for the jquery ajax to receive it and do some javascript magic according to that response. But you have to code that custom bit.

The form will most likely send the POST data to check.php, where it will all be processed, and it will then build a json encoded respopnse to reply to the page with the form. You need then some javascript code on that page to:

1. [Prevent default operation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) of the send button and bind to that click event the form submission with ajax.
2. Build the php code on check.php to do something with the POST data (`$_POST` array in PHP) and prepare a json encoded response (build an array and when done, echo the output of `json_encode`ing it).
3. build the javascript code to handle the ajax response from check.php

Some sample code on how to respond with php to a jquery ajax request [here](http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/responding-to-jquery-ajax-request-with-php/)